# Saving data in the database using velocity function template

Tags: java, velocity

Am using ETL, which is extract, transform and Load , i was able to extract and transform data from outside database, Now i want to be able to save this data into a db. Am trying to save symptoms, but these symptoms MUST be associated to a certain patient in the table, What , i did, i used patientId FROM symptom table to be equivalent to patient ID , In the db,

Here is my transform part
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oU20O.png)

so i went a head an create an load script, but am having a big challenge with finding the right script to save this information in the db, i will gladly appreciate for your help

```
#set($logFactory = $util.loadClass("org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory"))
#set($log = $logFactory.getLog("org.openmrs.api"))
#set($patientClass = "org.openmrs.Patient")
#set($encounterClass = "org.openmrs.Encounter")
#set($locationClass = "org.openmrs.Location")
#set($encounterTypeClass = "org.openmrs.EncounterType")
#set($calendarClass = $util.loadClass("java.util.Calendar"))
#set($obsClass = "org.openmrs.Obs")
$log.info("-----------------------")
$log.info("------ Load ----------")
$log.info("-----------------------")
#foreach($row in $rows)
  $log.info("row.patientId=$row.PatientId")
  $log.info("row.rash=$row.Rash")
  $log.info("row.Paraparesis=$row.Paraparesis")
  $log.info("row.DiabetesMellitus =$row.DiabetesMellitus ")
  $log.info("row.Diarrhea  =$row.Diarrhea ")
  $log.info("row.VisitDate  =$row.visitDate")
     #set($encounter = $util.newObject($encounterClass))
     #set($CONCEPT_UUIDS_FOR_PREDICTION_VALUE = ["1065", "1066"])
      #set($patient = $util.newObject($patientClass))
      #set($PatientId = $row.patientId)
      $log.info("PatientId= $row.PatientId")
      $log.info("------ patient id generated*********************************************************************----------")


      #set($patient = $patientService.getPatient($patientId))       $log.info("Patient= $PatientId")
      #set($encounter.patient = $patient)
      $log.info("encounter.patient = $patient")

      #set($calendar = $util.newObject($calendarClass))
      #set($encounter.encounterDateTime = $row.visitDate)
      $log.info("$encounter.encounterDateTime = $row.visitDate")


    #set($location = $util.newObject($locationClass))
    #set($locationUuid = "3b7617c9-778f-4f48-83e7-5514eb6ed946")
    $encounter.location = $locationService.getLocationByUuid($locationUuid)
    $log.info("$encounter.location")


    #set($encounterType = $util.newObject($encounterType))
    #set($encounterTypeUuid = "43c3630f-abfe-4fe1-8c92-b73b65199a3d")
    #set($encounter.encounterType = $encounterService.getEncounterTypeByUuid($encounterTypeUuid))
    $log.info("$encounter.encounterType")

    #set($obsList = [])
    #set($obsDiarrhoea = $util.newObject($obs))
    #set($conceptDiarrhoea = $conceptService.getConceptByName("Diarrhoea"))
    #set($obsDiarrhoea.concept = $conceptDiarrhoea)
    #set($obsDiarrhoea.setValueCoded($conceptDiarrhoea))
    $log.info("$ $obsDiarrhoea.setValueCoded($conceptDiarrhoea)")

    $obsList.add($obsDiarrhoea)
    $log.info("$obsDiarrhoea")

    #set($encounter.setObs($obsList))
    $log.info("$encounter.setObs($obsList)")
    $encounterService.saveEncounter($encounter)

    #if($encounterService == $null)
        $log.info("Encounter Service is null")
    #end


      $log.info("------ setting patient by id, here i used patient service to set patient by its id *********************************************************************----------")
      $log.info("------ attach an encounter to the patient, or populate encounter with patient using patient id*******)
```